# For inserting the first element of a binary tree, do you put it on the left or right?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

So I'm trying to create a binary tree in JavaScript

```
function ToBinaryTree ( arr )
{
    // creates a binary tree from an array arr of comparable objects

    this.Tree = { left: undefined, right: undefined };

    this.CreateNode = function ( value )
    {
          return { val : undefined, left : undefined, right : undefined }
    };
    this.Insert = function (elem)
    {
          var node = this.CreateNode(elem); 
        if ( this.Tree.left == undefined ) 
        // ... ??
    };

    // insert elements from array provided in "constructor"
    arr.forEach(function(x){
        this.Insert(x); 
    }.bind(this));

    this.Contains = function (elem)
    {
         // ...
    };

    return this;
}
```

and I can't figure out whether the very first element inserted should go on the `right` or `left`, and if it is, say, the `left` (`this.Tree.left`), then do I check that there are no elements inserted by checking `this.Tree.left == undefined` ???

Comment: each node has a value, left child node, and right child node, including the root node. so store the first element in the value of the root node.

Comment: you can change `arr.forEach(function(x){
        this.Insert(x); 
    }.bind(this));` to `arr.forEach(function(x){
        this.Insert(x); 
    }, this);`

Answer (score 1):

The first element goes on the root:

```
this.CreateNode = function (value) {
  return { 
    val: value,      // Store the root value here instead of undefined
    left: undefined, 
    right: undefined 
  };
};
```

p.s. Just realized this bug is not the only problem, and you also have a "Tree" constructor(?)... Don't try to distinguish Nodes from the Tree as a whole, in most cases it's simpler to assume the tree is the same as its root node and to have an additional "outside" static insert method that can deal with a "null" or undefined tree parameter (returning a new tree as needed)

p.p.s. If you use undefined as an empty tree marker, you can just overwrite the value on insert.